# Rails > 3.1 How to serve images from application.js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I've put an image inside the `app/assets/images`directory and now I want to serve it from my `application.js` file.

Something like:

```
beforeSend: function() {
  ('#any_div').html("<img src='/assets/loading.gif'>");
}
```

It tries to load from my current controller and I get:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/users/loading.gif
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

Any tip here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution.

In my `config/application.rb` file I had to add the following line:

`config.serve_static_assets = true`

and reboot the local webserver.

That's it! Hope it helps someone.